# How can I generate more Subkeys from an existing MasterKey, without invalidating already issued subkeys using Shamir Secret Sharing in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, galois-field

I have a Shamir Secret Sharing implementation in Java and I want to be able to generate more Subkeys, without invalidating the old subkeys.
I am currently using an implementation with GF256, and generating Subkeys once works. But as soon as generate another Subkey Set, and I try to combine them, it doesn't recreate the MasterKey anymore.
What do I have to change?

ShamirSecretSharing.java:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class ShamirSecretSharing
{
    private final int numberOfShares;
    private final int keyThreshold;
    private final GF256 gf256;

    ShamirSecretSharing(int numberOfShares, int keyThreshold, GF256 gf256)
    {
        this.numberOfShares = numberOfShares;
        this.keyThreshold = keyThreshold;
        this.gf256 = gf256;
    }

    public Map<Integer, byte[]> split(byte[] masterKey)
    {
        if (StringUtil.isBlankOrMissing(masterKey))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Master-Key must not be null or empty");
        }

        byte[][] subKeyValues = new byte[numberOfShares][masterKey.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < masterKey.length; i++)
        {
            byte[] polynomial = gf256.generatePolynomialOfDegree(keyThreshold - 1, masterKey[i]);
            for (int x = 1; x <= numberOfShares; x++)
            {
                subKeyValues[x - 1][i] = gf256.evaluatePolynomial(polynomial, (byte) x);
            }
        }

        Map<Integer, byte[]> subKeys = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < subKeyValues.length; i++)
        {
            subKeys.put(i + 1, subKeyValues[i]);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(subKeys);
    }

    public byte[] join(Map<Integer, byte[]> subKeys)
    {
        if (subKeys == null || subKeys.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sub-Keys must not be null");
        }

        final byte[] masterKey = new byte[((byte[])subKeys.values().toArray()[0]).length];
        for (int i = 0; i < masterKey.length; i++)
        {
            byte[][] points = new byte[subKeys.size()][2];
            int j = 0;
            for (Entry<Integer, byte[]> entry : subKeys.entrySet())
            {
                points[j][0] = entry.getKey().byteValue();
                points[j][1] = entry.getValue()[i];
                j++;
            }

            masterKey[i] = gf256.interpolatePolynomials(points);
        }

        return masterKey;
    }

    public static ShamirSecretSharingBuilder builder()
    {
        return new ShamirSecretSharingBuilder();
    }
}
```

GF256.java:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

class GF256
{
    private static final byte[] LOGARITHMIC_TABLE = {
            (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x1a,
            (byte) 0xc6, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0xee,
            (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x34,
            (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xc8,
            (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x1d,
            (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xe4,
            (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x65,
            (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x24,
            (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xda,
            (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xd0,
            (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x40,
            (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x30,
            (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0xe2,
            (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x6e,
            (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x3a,
            (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0xba,
            (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x5e,
            (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x73,
            (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xf4,
            (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0xd5,
            (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x75,
            (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xcb,
            (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0x7f,
            (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xec,
            (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x7b,
            (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x60,
            (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0xaa,
            (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x90,
            (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xcf,
            (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x39,
            (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0x14,
            (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0xab,
            (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x2e,
            (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x99,
            (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xc5,
            (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x80,
            (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x07,
    };

    private static final byte[] EXPONENTIAL_TABLE = {
            (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x55,
            (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xf8,
            (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xd8,
            (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x0a,
            (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x5c,
            (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xbe,
            (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x53,
            (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0xcc,
            (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0xb2,
            (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x3b,
            (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x18,
            (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0xd0,
            (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xb3,
            (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xc4,
            (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x0b,
            (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0xa3,
            (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xad,
            (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0x20,
            (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xd2,
            (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56,
            (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x5e, (byte) 0xe2,
            (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xed,
            (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x9f,
            (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x7e,
            (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x89,
            (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x23,
            (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0xc8,
            (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x63,
            (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x77,
            (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xcf,
            (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xa8,
            (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0xc6, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x0e,
            (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x8d,
            (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0xf2,
            (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0x84,
            (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0xb4,
            (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x0f,
            (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x72,
            (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xe1,
            (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0xf7,
            (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xaa,
            (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xeb,
            (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xab,
            (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x14,
            (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0xb8,
            (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0x67,
            (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0xa6,
            (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x83,
            (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x7f,
            (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x76,
            (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x30,
            (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xbb,
            (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x7d,
            (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x93,
            (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x16,
            (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x5d,
            (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x41,
            (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x5e, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x40,
            (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xbf,
            (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0xac,
            (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0xdf,
            (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xc1,
            (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x25,
            (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xfc,
            (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x09,
            (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x46,
            (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x8b,
            (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0xc6,
            (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xee,
            (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x85,
            (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x4b,
            (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x1c,
            (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0xf6,
    };

    private final SecureRandom secureRandom;

    private GF256(SecureRandom secureRandom)
    {
        this.secureRandom = secureRandom;
    }

    /**
     * As GF(256) is just GF(2^8) we can use binary operators to do mathematical operations.
     * So addition is equal to XOR.
     */
    byte add(byte a, byte b)
    {
        return (byte) (a^b);
    }

    /**
     * Subtract b from a using addition
     */
    byte subtract(byte a, byte b)
    {
        return add(a, b);
    }

    /**
     * Multiply in finite field. Uses lookup table as it is far more performant.
     * Uses Reed Solomon codes to do the multiplication.
     */
    byte multiply(byte a, byte b)
    {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return EXPONENTIAL_TABLE[
                Byte.toUnsignedInt(LOGARITHMIC_TABLE[Byte.toUnsignedInt(a)])
                        + Byte.toUnsignedInt(LOGARITHMIC_TABLE[Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)])
                ];
    }

    /**
     * Divide byte a with byte b.
     * Uses multiplication with the inverse of b
     */
    byte divide(byte a, byte b)
    {
        return multiply(a, EXPONENTIAL_TABLE[255 - Byte.toUnsignedInt(LOGARITHMIC_TABLE[Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)])]);
    }

    /**
     * Evaluate the polynom with the given coefficients and the value.
     * Uses Horner's method
     * @param coefficient of the polynom
     * @param value to evaluate
     * @return the result of the evaluation
     */
    byte evaluatePolynomial(byte[] coefficient, byte value)
    {
        byte result = 0;
        for (int i = coefficient.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            result = add(multiply(result, value), coefficient[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    int getDegreeOfPolynomial(byte[] polynom)
    {
        for (int i = polynom.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (polynom[i] != 0)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    byte[] generatePolynomialOfDegree(int degree, byte value)
    {
        byte[] polynomial = new byte[degree + 1];

        do
        {
            secureRandom.nextBytes(polynomial);
        }
        while (getDegreeOfPolynomial(polynomial) != degree);

        polynomial[0] = value;
        return polynomial;
    }

    byte interpolatePolynomials(byte[][] pointsOnPolynomial)
    {
        byte x = 0;
        byte y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsOnPolynomial.length; i++)
        {
            byte aX = pointsOnPolynomial[i][0];
            byte aY = pointsOnPolynomial[i][1];

            byte li = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < pointsOnPolynomial.length; j++)
            {
                byte bX = pointsOnPolynomial[j][0];
                if (i != j)
                {
                    li = multiply(li, divide(subtract(x, bX), subtract(aX, bX)));
                }
            }
            y = add(y, multiply(li, aY));
        }
        return y;
    }

    private static final class InstanceHolder
    {
        private static final GF256 INSTANCE = new GF256(new SecureRandom());
    }

    static GF256 getInstance()
    {
        return InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Calling Code:

```
@Test
            void subKeysShouldRestoreMasterKey()
            {
                //given
                byte[] toSplit = "MasterKey".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Map<Integer, byte[]> parts = secretSharing.split(toSplit);
                Map<Integer, byte[]> partsTwo = secretSharing.split(toSplit);
                Map<Integer, byte[]> subKeysToUse = Map.of(1, parts.get(1), 3, partsTwo.get(3));

                //when
                byte[] restoredSecret = secretSharing.join(subKeysToUse);

                //then
                assertThat(new String(restoredSecret, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                        .isEqualTo(new String(toSplit, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
```

I tried to generate additional SubKeys, and expected that I could mix them with the already existing subkeys to recreate the secret. But that didn't work.